# browser default loader icon not shown while clicking any link inside an iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, browser, download

While accessing any page inside an iframe when I click on any download link or url, browser default loader doesn't work.

I have loaded jqueryui page inside an iframe in below example. when I click on Stable link below Quick download section, it downloads zip file but during download it doesn't show loading bar in browser.

[image]

```
<iframe src="https://jqueryui.com/" title="Jquery" width="1024px" height="768px"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/1egsp74b/2/

I am scratching my head for this weird issue as originally in my application file being downloaded takes time and its frustrating for user to wait for it without any indication of something is in progress.

Is it possible to display **default browser loader** of parent page when we download / navigate in child iframe?